# actionbar icon looks smaller in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using voicemail icon for my app actionbar item. But compare to other icons,  it looks very smaller. I am using the same sizes - 48x48, 36x36,24x24 and 18x18 to this also.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [guide](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) says 32dp, that means you are too small.

> Action bar icons for phones should be 32x32 dp.

That would mean the following pixel sizes:

```
 ldpi: 24x24 pixel
 mdpi: 32x32 pixel
 hdpi: 48x48 pixel
xhpdi: 64x64 pixel
```

Comment: Well you can only provide images based on pixel size but android works also with "dp" and the calculation between dp and pixel is based on the dpi the device have. mdpi = 1, ldpi = 0.75, hdpi = 1.5 and xhdpi = 2. Can all be read in the [screen support documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Even i have applied with the above values the Voicemail icon still looks smaller than others. Why ?